# Trying to access a network drive via GitLab Runner script but get an error

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using the CI component of GitLab and I get this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

When I try to access a mapped network drive in the script. When try to access the drive normally from my PC (the same one running the service), I can see all the mapped drives.

Here is the script from the .gitlab-yml:

```
variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: "TestApp"
  STAGING_PATH: X:\some\network\location\%PROJECT_NAME%
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "starting build for %PROJECT_NAME% at %TIME%"
  ...
  artifacts:
    name: "%PROJECT_NAME%"
    paths:
      - '%PROJECT_NAME%/bin/Release'
    expire_in: 1 week
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
    - dir "X:"  << ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    - net use
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: staging
  only:
  - master
```

I have used the `net use` command to list the network locations it can see but that list is also empty. Is there any way to make gitlab-runner see these network locations?

The runner I am using is the one windows binary obtainable [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html). The config toml file is:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "Haroon-PC"
  url = "http://ae-ubuntu/"
  token = "fd84211a6d37d88d4903317c85ce7a"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

Comment: Can you specify what is the runner and the executor you are using? Is this the complete `gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: Hi @RuwankaMadhushan, thanks for taking a look at it this. I have added the details to the initial question. As for the yml file, the only bit I took out was the build steps (the ... section). It's just some standard MSBuild and nuget restore stuff that you would use for .NET applications. I can add it if that helps

Comment: Can you run that failing command successfully in the runner machine? If it fails then problem lies in your runner machine not the CI configuration (simply your runner cannot find/run specific command successfully)

Comment: Both the `dir X:' and the 'net use' commands work as expected on the runner machine. I'm wondering if there is an issue with permissions or network visibility regarding the gitlab-runner. My network environment is a windows domain and I normally access the network drive by mapping the UNC to a drive letter on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

The built in system account (default) for the gitlab-runner service does not have access to the external network drives.

You'll have to run the gitlab-runner service using a user account that has access to the network drives. When starting the service, follow the directions under "Run service using user account".

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

joe.schuellers hint helped me a lot to access net-drives with the runner and it will work.
Just install your runner with

```
gitlab-runner.exe install --user ENTER-YOUR-USERNAME --password ENTER-YOUR-PASSWORD
```